# What symbol is " \ "

Tags: c++

in the code there are "\" symbols each line but I have no idea what's mean
is it for the file handling?

```
#define GENERATESTRUCT(Name, Column, DataType) \
string a(#Name); \
int index = 0; \
a.append(".h"); \
FILE* file = fopen(a.c_str(), "wt+"); \
fprintf(file, "#pragma once\n"); \
fprintf(file, "#include <string>\n"); \
fprintf(file, "#include <cstdlib>\n"); \
fprintf(file, "using namespace std;\n\n"); \
fprintf(file, "enum E%s{\n", #Name); \
while (index < column.size()) \
{ \
    fprintf(file, "\te%s_%s,\n", #Name, column[index].c_str()); \
    ++index; \
} \
fprintf(file, "};\n\n"); \
fprintf(file, "class %s{\n", #Name); \
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuation marker. C++ macros are not allowed carriage returns. Strictly this should all be on one line,  but that would be difficult to read.

The `\` tells the preprocessor to ignore the carriage return.

Strictly speaking, the very last one is unnecessary and could cause you problems in any code that immediately follows, which could be regarded as part of the macro.